# Put and Get JSON object from Nashorn to MongoDB

Tags: java, nashorn

i want to store JSON Objects from js-scripts running in Nashorn in a MongoDB and get them back again. 
The provided API functions look like:

```
db.put("key", {"mykey":[1,2,3]})
var result = db.get("key")
```

There are two issues i don't know how to deal with them:

1. On the Java-side i'm getting a ScriptObjectMirror that implements Map. So if a got a JSON-Object with an Array inside it's already broken here.
    e.g. `{"key":[1,2,3]} -> {"key": {"0":1, "1":2, "2": 3}}`
2. When JSON object is read from DB it's not possible to `JSON.stringify` the object. It just returns undefined. Isn' threre any possiblity to inject a JSON object from Java into Nashorn so that is compatible for `JSON.stringify?`

Do you have any suggestions for my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From JS, you can use `var jsonResult = Java.asJSONCompatible(result)` to get back a custom wrapper where JS Arrays are exposed as Java Lists.

From Java, you can use `ScriptObjectMirror.wrapAsJSONCompatible(obj)`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solutions, from JS to Java, works as expected. The problem is that we are providing an API for other developers and we don't want to tell them to use Java.asJSONCompatible in the JS-Code.

I can't get the 2nd solution, from Java to JS, work.
Here's my Test:

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class NashornJsonConversionTest {

    ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

    private class MyJsonWrapper extends HashMap<String, Object>{
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldStringifyCorrectly() throws ScriptException {
        String exepectedStringified = "{\"value\":1}";

        MyJsonWrapper myJsonWrapper = new MyJsonWrapper();
        myJsonWrapper.put("value", 1);

        scriptEngine.put("jsonObject", ScriptObjectMirror.wrapAsJSONCompatible(myJsonWrapper, null));

        Assert.assertEquals(1, scriptEngine.eval("jsonObject.value"));

        String result = (String) scriptEngine.eval("JSON.stringify(jsonObject)");
        Assert.assertEquals(exepectedStringified, result);

        //Expected :{"value":1}
        //Actual   :null
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetJSONWithArrayAsList() throws ScriptException {
        Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) scriptEngine.eval("Java.asJSONCompatible({value:[1,2,3]})");
        List<Integer> values = (List<Integer>) result.get("value");
        Assert.assertEquals(values.size(), 3);
        // works as expected
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the object to a "plain" object in nashorn. Currently your script engine see a mirror.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bernicc/00g6acp1/

```js
/**
 * This function convert an object coming from nashorn to a plain object.
 * Instead of using <code>JSON.parse(value);</code> this method does only create new instances for objects.
 * There is no need to parse a number, string or boolean.
 *
 * @param value the object which should be returned as clean object
 * @returns {Object} the clean object
 */
toCleanObject: function (value) {
    switch (typeof value) {
        case "object":
            var ret = {};
            for (var key in value) {
                ret[key] = this.toCleanObject(value[key]);
            }
            return ret;
        default: //number, string, boolean, null, undefined
            return value;
    }
}
```

Above is your test with a minified version of the function. For this example wrapAsJSONCompatible is not necessary.

```java
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class NashornJsonConversionTest {

    ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

    private class MyJsonWrapper extends HashMap<String, Object>{
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldStringifyCorrectly() throws ScriptException {
        String exepectedStringified = "{\"value\":1}";

        MyJsonWrapper myJsonWrapper = new MyJsonWrapper();
        myJsonWrapper.put("value", 1);

        // for this example wrapAsJSONCompatible is not necessary
        //scriptEngine.put("jsonObject", ScriptObjectMirror.wrapAsJSONCompatible(myJsonWrapper, null));
        scriptEngine.put("jsonObject", myJsonWrapper);

        scriptEngine.eval("function toCleanObject(t){switch(typeof t){case\"object\":var e={};for(var n in t)e[n]=toCleanObject(t[n]);return e;default:return t}}");
        scriptEngine.eval("jsonObject = toCleanObject(jsonObject);");
        Assert.assertEquals(1, scriptEngine.eval("jsonObject.value"));

        String result = (String) scriptEngine.eval("JSON.stringify(jsonObject)");
        Assert.assertEquals(exepectedStringified, result);

        //Expected :{"value":1}
        //Actual   :null
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetJSONWithArrayAsList() throws ScriptException {
        Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) scriptEngine.eval("Java.asJSONCompatible({value:[1,2,3]})");
        List<Integer> values = (List<Integer>) result.get("value");
        Assert.assertEquals(values.size(), 3);
        // works as expected
    }

}
```

Kind regards from Berlin, Bernard